# Can't access ref object value imported from different javascript file

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am trying to create a dynamic fetchPage / pagination javascript / vuejs function, where I can use this data in my page with v-for.

So, I created this dashboardDataManager.js script:

```
// dataManager.js
import axios from 'axios';
import { ref } from 'vue';

export class DataManager {
  constructor(dataSource, itemsPerPage) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
    this.itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;

    this.currentPage = ref(1);
    this.data = ref([]);
    this.totalItems = ref(0);
    this.totalPages = ref(0);
    this.itemsCurrentPage = ref(0);
    this.fromRecord = ref(0);
    this.toRecord = ref(0);
  }

  async fetchPage() {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`/data/${this.dataSource}?page=${this.currentPage.value}`);
      this.data.value = response.data[this.dataSource].data;
      this.totalItems.value = response.data[this.dataSource].total;
      this.fromRecord.value = response.data[this.dataSource].from;
      this.toRecord.value = response.data[this.dataSource].to;
      this.totalPages.value = this.calculateTotalPages();
      this.itemsCurrentPage.value = this.calculateItemsCurrentPage();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error fetching ${this.dataSource}:`, error);
    }
  }

  calculateTotalPages() {
    return Math.ceil(this.totalItems.value / this.itemsPerPage);
  }

  calculateItemsCurrentPage() {
    const startIndex = (this.currentPage.value - 1) * this.itemsPerPage;
    const endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + this.itemsPerPage, this.totalItems.value);
    return endIndex - startIndex;
  }
}
```

In my dashboard.Vue page, I import this function, create new databaseManagers and initialize them onMounted:

```
<script setup>
// Imports
import { usePage, Head, Link, useForm } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
import axios from 'axios';

// Create new DataManager to import data
const contacts = new DataManager('contacts', 5);
const contactEvents = new DataManager('contactevents', 5);

onMounted(async () => {
await Promise.all([
  contactEvents.fetchPage(),
  contacts.fetchPage(),
  console.log(contactEvents.data),
]);

</script>
```

I added these logs to check the output. I can see that my fetchPage function works and that all correct data is returned:

```
{
    "__v_isShallow": false,
    "__v_isRef": true,
    "_rawValue": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "created_at": "2023-11-20T08:16:38.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-11-20T08:16:38.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "created_at": "2023-11-20T08:17:34.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-11-20T08:17:34.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "created_at": "2023-11-20T09:03:57.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-11-20T09:03:57.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "created_at": "2023-11-20T09:16:32.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-11-20T09:16:32.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "created_at": "2023-11-20T09:53:37.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-11-20T09:53:37.000000Z"
        }
    ],
    "_value": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "created_at": "2023-11-20T08:16:38.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-11-20T08:16:38.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "created_at": "2023-11-20T08:17:34.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-11-20T08:17:34.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "created_at": "2023-11-20T09:03:57.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-11-20T09:03:57.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "created_at": "2023-11-20T09:16:32.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-11-20T09:16:32.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "created_at": "2023-11-20T09:53:37.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-11-20T09:53:37.000000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, I cannot use this data inside my v-for div:

```
<div v-for="(event, index) in contactEvents.data" :key="event.id">
 {{event.id}}
</div>
```

It shows nothing.

Also:

```
contactEvents.data.value
contactEvents.data._value
contactEvents.data._rawValue
```

do not output anything.

While in the console I can see that the correct data is there, as added to this post.

How do I access this reactive data and cycle through it to output it on the page?

I have no idea how to fix this...